# How do I import bookmarks into Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security

How do I import bookmarks to Tor Browser? I did it before, but they are gone and now I cannot find the "import bookmarks" function I used last time.

Comment: The correct answer is: Ctrl+Shift+B to open the Bookmarks Manager / "Library" window. From there you can import/export.

Answer (score 6):

Do the following steps one by one:

1. Click on the **Bookmarks icon** (the clipboard icon not the star icon) next to the location bar
2. Select **Show all Bookmarks**
3. Click on **Import and Backup** menu in the new window
4. Select **Restore**
5. Click on **Choose file** from the submenu, and select the file where you previously exported your bookmarks to.

You are done.

Comment: In my case there is no clipboard icon, but replacing step 1 with clicking the "burger" menu (3 horizontal lines) and selecting Bookmarks is an equivalent step.

Comment: there is no show bookmarks in TOR

Comment: Missing step 0, to create the backup/export in your normal browser so you can import it.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the answer provided by *guest*, you can use **Firefox Sync** to sync your bookmarks from another TorBrowser or Firefox browser on the same device or on another device. You can access it from the **menu icon** in the toolbar, choose **Options**, and then choose **Sync** from the top of the new window. You can configure your Sync options there and add your device to your Sync account.

Comment: The above answer 2 seems to be totally wrong as there is no icon of any sort next to the location bar. Are there any other answers to this problem? Ahhh!!!! After as lot of faffing around I finally discovered that there is a "bookmarks manager" hidden away which is found by opening the settings selecting bookmarks then clicking on Bookmarks Toolbar. If only that had been mentioned previously...

Comment: Please keep in mind that the other 2 answers were probably valid when they were posted almost 2 years ago. I don't remember exactly, but Firefox did have a major UI overhaul in 2015 with the Australis update, and many things were moved around.

Comment: Using Firefox Sync to get bookmarks into Tor is not a good idea because by default more than bookmarks will be synced. In particular: settings and add-ons are synced from your Firefox installation which could destroy the anonymity given by Tor, or could mess up you Firefox settings!